# Is this plant "Hedera canariensis"?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Location: South India

I found this plant beside **bus stop**.

[image]

Side view of the Plant.

[image]

Actually, [Wikipedia says *Hedera canariensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedera_canariensis) is "native to the Atlantic coast in Canary islands and northern Africa", but it is growing in India, so is it really *Hedera canariensis*?

Comment: What makes you think that could be *Hedera canariensis*? It does not look anything like it ...

Comment: Looking at your profile, you are using this community to provide the species identification for everything you find, until you find something nobody knows and you can finally declare you found an unknown species. For one, it is highly unlikely you will find an unknown species near a bus stop. Or anywhere near where humans are. Otherwise, please start to read up on how to identify plants and do some preliminary work. We are not some kind of "free expert service".

Comment: Apparently looks like [*Xanthium strumarium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthium_strumarium) (asteraceae) and [*Chrozophora rottleri*](http://www.eflorakkl.in/Details.php?id=67) (Euphorbiaceae) .

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Well! your plants exactly match with my plant, but I added **side view** of my plant. does it **ring any bells**?

Comment: @ManoharRantam Sorry I couldn't tell without its sexual-reproductive structure. Could also be something else than the 2 i mentioned in the previous comment. However never like *Hedera canariensis*. The title could be potentially misleading.